# Google AdMob ads don't show up on the Unity game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob

I did everything on Google's official AdMob tutorial. Test ad was showing up on the editor but when i try it on my phone there are no ads. Google approved my account and still nothing shows up. What do i have to do now?
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    BannerView _banner;
    string bannerId = "banner-id";

    void Start()
    {
        MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
        RequestBanner();
    }
    
    void RequestBanner()
    {
        _banner = new BannerView(bannerId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        _banner.LoadAd(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach a listener to the `BannerView` & log / check what is the error or error-code printed in the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Put banner test ID in `string bannerId` and in your `Start()` function call this function `_banner.Show()` after `RequestBanner();` function. It will defiantly work.